# Is it possible to flip a string in Python "around" a character?

Tags: python, string

For example let's say I have two strings:

We have the string `hello-world` and the string `world`.

I want to create a function called `flip(str, arg)` that basically takes the string, and "flips" the characters before and after the "arg", if any.

So `hello-world` passed into `flip("hello-world", "-")` would become `world-hello` and `flip("world", "-")` would still remain `world`.

An example implementation is as follows, but I am wondering if there is a library function or something for this (I only need in one location, making a function doesn't seem right). I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

```
def flip(s, arg):
    if arg not in s:
        return s

    index = s.find(arg)
    return s[index+1:] + arg + s[:index]
```

Comment: What's the expected output of `"hello-my-world"`, is it `"world-my-hello"`, `"world-hello-my"` or `"my-world-hello"`?

Comment: did u try to split the s with '-' and append the array after that flip the array[0] with array[1] ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero that is not a case I am handling. Only <str>-<str>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.partition`, then reverse the splits and join:

```
def flip(s, arg):
    return ''.join(s.partition(arg)[::-1])

flip('hello-world', '-')
# 'world-hello'

flip('world', '-')
# 'world'
```

---

Note that if the string has multiple occurrences of `arg`, the string is partitioned on the first one *only*.

```
flip("hello-my-world", '-')
# 'my-world-hello'
```

If you want a complete flip (reversal), you may instead consider `str.split` and `str.join`:

```
def flip2(s, arg):
    return arg.join(s.split(arg)[::-1])

flip2("hello-my-world", '-')
# 'world-my-hello'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for one liner you can do the following -

```
"-".join("Hello-world".split('-')[::-1])
```

so for a more general solution, you can first define arg, and string:

```
arg = '-'
string = 'hello-world'
```

and then use -

```
arg.join(string.split(arg)[::-1])
```